# Use different objdump in kcachegrind

Tags: objdump, kcachegrind

Kcachegrind will use the default one objdump by default (to get asm code from ELF).

Is it possible to force Kcachegrind to use different objdump, e.g. `/home/os_gx/local/bin/arm-linux/objdump`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to accomplish the same thing myself. I managed to do it in KCachegrind 0.4.6 by creating a symbolic link name objdump (pointing to the objdump you want to use) and then adding "." to PATH. In the later versions of KCachegrind (the version that comes with 11.04 for instance), this just gives the program counter and jumps for some reason which is a bit of a shame.

Comment: there is a objdump output parser inside the kcachegrind. may be your objdump has different format.

Comment: Yep, it seems like it, but it used to work with KCachegrind 0.4.6, so it must have been something that changed when they changed the project into QCachegrind. I will add it as a feature suggestion on the project homepage.